# How to create a function that assigns property values to other other properties?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, properties

I would like to have a `function` that can loop through specific child `properties` of a `variable` and assign those `variables` to another `variable` with the same structure.

Assigning the current values to a new `variable` is useful if the original `variable`'s `properties` will change values often.

I can't seem to think of the correct logic for looping through specific `properties` only. The goal is to prevent assigning individual `properties` line by line, in a case like

```
objToLookAt.firstProperty.a = objToLookAtCopy.firstProperty.a;
```

Here's the JavaScript with the structure:

```
var objToLookAt = {
    firstProperty: {
        a: 84, b: 66, c: 37, d: 20
    },
    secondProperty: {
        a: 79, b: 26, c: 55, d: 84
    }, 
    skipThirdProperty: {
        a: 79, b: 26, c: 55, d: 84
    },  
    skipFourthProperty: {
        a: 79, b: 26, c: 55, d: 84
    }   
};

var objToLookAtCopy = {
    firstProperty: {
        a: null, b: null, c: null, d: null
    },
    secondProperty: {
        a: null, b: null, c: null, d: null
    }    
};

function AssignObjValues(objWithValues, objToAssignValuesTo){
    //loop code goes here
    //for each property inside objToLookAt, assign every child of firstProperty and secondProperty
    //to = objToLookAtCopy child properties  

    console.debug(objToAssignValuesTo); //display only the first two properties in console
}

AssignObjValues(objToLookAt, objToLookAtCopy);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution to have firstProperty and secondProperty hard coded instead of checking if the copy object has the property to assign the value to isn't a very flexible solution.

To deep copy objects is a bit tricky in JavaScript. Assuming you only work with object literals and no constructor functions created objects (like Array) you could do the following (I have uncapitalised the function name because it would suggest the function is a constructor if capitalize it):

```
var objToLookAt = {
  firstProperty: {
    a: 84, b: 66, c: 37, d: 20
  },
  secondProperty: {
    a: 79, b: 26, c: 55, d: 84
  },
  skipThirdProperty: {
    a: 79, b: 26, c: 55, d: 84
  },
  skipFourthProperty: {
    a: 79, b: 26, c: 55, d: 84
  }
};

var objToLookAtCopy = {
  firstProperty: {
    a: null, b: null, d: null
  },
  secondProperty: {
    a: null, b: null, c: null, d: null
  }
};

function assignObjValues(objWithValues, objToAssignValuesTo) {
  for (var prop in objWithValues) {
    //deep copy object values by recursively calling assignObjValues
    //  but only if objToAssingValuesTo has the same property and is
    //  object as well
    if (objWithValues.hasOwnProperty(prop) &&
            objWithValues[prop] instanceof Object &&
            objToAssignValuesTo.hasOwnProperty &&
            objToAssignValuesTo.hasOwnProperty(prop) &&
            objToAssignValuesTo[prop] instanceof Object) {
      assignObjValues(objWithValues[prop], objToAssignValuesTo[prop]);
      continue;
    }
    //assign primitive values only (string, boolean, number)
    if (objWithValues.hasOwnProperty(prop) &&
            objToAssignValuesTo.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      objToAssignValuesTo[prop] = objWithValues[prop];
    }
  }
}

assignObjValues(objToLookAt, objToLookAtCopy);

objToLookAtCopy.secondProperty.b = "Hello World";
console.log(objToLookAt.secondProperty.b)//=26
console.log(objToLookAt.secondProperty === objToLookAtCopy.secondProperty);//false
//notice that c ins't copied because it isn't defined in the copy object
console.log(objToLookAtCopy.firstProperty);//=Object { a=84,  b=66,  d=20}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this code does not copy the necessary values. It might seem that way given the sample two vars. I am trying to copy values from an existing JS library that has a lot of properties. This code copies almost all properties and skips the important ones such as `a` and `b`.

Comment: @MCSharp It'll skip any value that is not defined in the copy variable as you requested. What does a console.log say of the properties that are not copied? And what does console.log(propertyThatIsntCopied.constructor) stay?

Comment: The code does not seem to work with other libraries such as THREE.JS. If the object has the same properties as a three.js object, all values are copied over. Many are left as null. If you can update the code to properly work with other libraries, I'll be glad to change the correct answer.

Comment: @MCSharp don't need to, just added an answer that will copy object literal values only if the copy object has the same members defined. As to why it doesn't work with your I cannot say, maybe the copy object does not define the same values, maybe the original object has values that come from constructor functions and have members that come from their prototype. Without the console log I can only guess. If your code works as it should then your problem is solved.

Comment: You're right. The function copies the values. Firebug shows the log correctly while Chrome adds extra prototype parts. I've created a simple setup here: jsfiddle.net/VsWb9/1753 with a cube to copy it's values. It works properly in the example. Your answer is suited better for the question I've asked. I have accepted your answer.

Comment: @MCSharp I can see that rotation comes from prototype of cube, cube.hasOwnProperty("rotation") is false. If you want to copy such values in your copy object just remove the `objWithValues.hasOwnProperty(prop)` in the if statements. The copy is not an exact copy but does represent the data of the original object. An exact copy of cube could be created with `cube.clone()` but then you have all of cube's members again.

Comment: Thanks again for the flexible solution. I tried this with and without `objWithValues.hasOwnProperty(prop)`. Both return the same values which are correct. I don't see a difference.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, a simple `for in` loop will work.

```
var objToLookAt = {
    firstProperty: {
        a: 84, b: 66, c: 37, d: 20
    },
    secondProperty: {
        a: 79, b: 26, c: 55, d: 84
    }    
};
```

and then if you want to copy

```
var newFirst = {
    a: 1, b: 2, c: 3
}
```

over, you could simply do

```
for (var prop in newFirst){
    //prevent possible crap from the prototype from getting copied over
    if (newFirst.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { 
        objToLookAt.firstProperty[prop] = newFirst[prop]
    }
}
```

So for your code, it would be something like this:

```
function AssignObjValues(objWithValues, objToAssignValuesTo){
    for (var prop in objWithValues){
        //prevent possible crap from the prototype from getting copied over
        if (objWithValues.hasOwnProperty(prop)){ 
            objToAssignValuesTo[prop] = objWithValues[prop]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very close to what I am looking for. I didn't fully elaborate in my question. How can I assign only the desired properties to the new var? If say there were more than 2 properties in the original var.

Comment: @MCSharp - you could do that many different ways.  You'd have to specify the properties you wanted to assign somehow.  Possible pass in an array of property names, and loop through *that* instead of the for in loop like I have.

Comment: the for in loop works great for assigning every property to the new var. If I do a `console.debug` on the new object, all properties from the previous object show up. That loop for specific property names is what I'm struggling with. Not sure how to translate it to code.

Comment: cool - glad you got it, @MCSharp.  I'm not terribly sure what it is you did, so I'll just leave the answer as is - I think it's generic enough to help future visitors.  - or you can update your answer with the code you used.